# Changing the DW_COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL for a Synapse SQL pool database inside Visual Studio

Tags: azure-synapse-analytics

I'm implementing a database for a Synapse dedicated SQL pool inside a Visual Studio 2022 environment with SSDT.
In particular, I'm writing some scripts to create hash distributed tables with more hash columns and not only one: these scripts go in error because it is need to change the DW_COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL of the database.

I've tried to specify the script to perform this alter statement:

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET DW_COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 50;
```

but also this script causes an error.
Now, how could I solve a such issue, please? Thanks